# Java replace any numbers in a URL between or after slashes

Tags: java, regex, replace

I've been banging my head against a wall for the last hour trying to come up with an eloquent way using Java (the application is in Java so I have to use it) to handle a particular problem.  I am trying to replace any number (even if it has leading zeros) in a RESTful URL with hashtags so that we can track how many times a particular call was made, regardless of ID.  Here are some examples of what I'm looking to do:

http://host.com/api/person/1234 needs to be http://host.com/api/person/#####

http://host.com/api/person/1234/jobs needs to be http://host.com/api/person/#####/jobs

http://host.com/api/person/1234/jobs/321 needs to be http://host.com/api/person/#####/jobs/#####

http://host.com/api/person/abc1234/jobs needs to stay http://host.com/api/person/abc1234/jobs

The hashtags that will be inserted will always be 5 hashtags to keep things uniform.  I have this working using two steps, I was trying to figure out a way using regex and replaceAll to do it in one, although if anyone else knows of a better way to do it in one step I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Sigh. Do kids really call the pound sign a "hashtag" these days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*replaceAll*()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) method with this simple `regex`:

```
(?<=/)\\d+
```

Which means "match all numbers after slash (`/`)".

**Example:**

```
List<String> urls = Arrays.asList("http://host.com/api/person/1234", "http://host.com/api/person/1234/jobs", "http://host.com/api/person/1234/jobs/321", "http://host.com/api/person/abc1234/jobs", "http://host.com/api/person/1234abc/jobs");
for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
   urls.set(i, urls.get(i).replaceAll("(?<=/)\\d+(?=/|$)", "#####"));
}
System.out.println(urls.toString());

// Result:
// [http://host.com/api/person/#####, http://host.com/api/person/#####/jobs, http://host.com/api/person/#####/jobs/#####, http://host.com/api/person/abc1234/jobs, host.com/api/person/1234abc/jobs]
```

<kbd>[**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/oL5tvr)</kbd>

Comment: This is pretty close to being the complete answer.  When running my test the one scenario it doesn't cover is if after the slash there are numbers followed by alpha characters.  The test is:
http://host.com/api/person/1234abc/jobs should not be altered but ends up being http://host.com/api/person/#####abc/jobs.  Still, plus 1 for answering the question based off of the information provided.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks @developer033